# Создание зарание неизвестного количества Dictionary

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Имеется `List<string>`, в котором содержатся логины пользователей, так вот, мне для каждого логина нужно создать свой `Dictionary<int, bool>`. Как понятно из названия, я заранее не знаю, сколько будет логинов, а значит, и сколько будет Dictionary. Очень прошу вашей помощи!

**Обновление**

Допустим, в List содержится 3 записи: "admin", "Sasha", "Masha". Так вот мне для каждой записи нужен свой Dictionary. Я делаю чат, и в Dictionary у меня будут содержаться id сообщения и прочитано ли оно, но так как чат с каждым по отдельности, мне нужно для каждого отдельный Dictionary.

Comment: а поконкретнее можно?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: вопрос в том, какая связь между элементами List и соответствующими Dictionary?

Comment: @Adept22: А в чём проблема? Цикл `for` не пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаём структуру

```
struct UserStruct
{
  string: Username;
  Dictionary<int,bool> IntBoolPair;
}
```

а в основном коде уже используем её:

```
List<UserStruct> userStruct = new List<UserStruct>();
```

Comment: По идее, не структуру, а класс, т. к. нужна семантика reference type.

Comment: Ну, из структуры класс не сложно сделать :)